# php redirect using session data

Tags: php, redirect, session-variables

im trying to write a function that redirects the user to their profile page when they try to access the index (home) page. i have been able to do this successfully from the login form using the POST data, but am having trouble pulling the session data in this way. Firefox says the server is redirecting in a way that will never complete.

This is what ive tried, as written in my general functions include:

```
function logged_in_redirect() {
if (logged_in() === true) {
    header('Location: '.$_SESSION['username'].'');
  //header('Location: '.$user_data['username'].'');   *NEITHER LINE WORKS
    exit();
}
}
```

and my index page on which im adding the redirect:

```
    <?php 
    include 'core/init.php';
    logged_in_redirect();
    include 'includes/overall/header.php'; 
    ?>        
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <p>Just a template.</p>

    <?php include 'includes/overall/footer.php'; ?>
```

and heres my init include:

```
    <?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    //error_reporting(0);

    require 'database/connect.php';
    require 'functions/general.php';
    require 'functions/users.php';

    if (logged_in() === true) {
        $session_user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $user_data = user_data($db, $session_user_id, 'user_id', 'username', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'stack_code');
        if (user_active($db, $user_data['username']) === false) {
          session_destroy();
          header('Location: index.php');
          exit();
        }
    }

    $errors = array();
    ?>
```

iv modified my .htaccess and everything else about the profile url is working fine. just this redirect is driving me up a wall today. Thanks!

Comment: I think that's something with your user's page that might be re-redirecting to the same page. Can we see it as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok simple, i just needed to pass the $user_data variable in my init through the redirect function, and also when i call the function:

```
function logged_in_redirect($user_data) {
if (logged_in() === true) {
    header('Location: '.$user_data['username'].''); 
    exit();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the page accessed if is the index page you move the user to the profile page. Like so:

```
$page = isset($_POST['page']) ? clear_get_tag($_POST['page']) : NULL;
        $session_user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $user_data = user_data($db, $session_user_id, 'user_id', 'username', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'stack_code');
switch($page){

case 'index':
case NULL:
if (logged_in() === true && !is_null($user_data) ) {
//call the redirect function here if the user is logged
}else{
// echo the index page
}
break;

case 'user':
echo 'user profile';
break;

default:
// Check if something else was called rather than defined pages, and returns the page depend on if the user is logged in.
if (logged_in() === true) {
header('Location: '.$user_data['username'].''); 
}else{
header('Location: index.php');
}
break;

}
```